# Can kernel's flushing/syncing of mmaped file interrupt a write() call?

Tags: filesystems, mmap

I know there is (shamefully) no way to prevent kernel from flushing dirty pages of files `mmap`-ed with `MAP_SHARED`, so to take the control back, I wanted to map a file with `MAP_PRIVATE`, then when I want to flush, I just `mmap` again using `MAP_SHARED`, then copy (from the private mapping) using `write` or `memcpy`, then flush with `msync` and finally unmap with `munmap`. Now I want to know, can kernel's flusher interrupt my write, resulting in my `msync` syncing that page (where `write` was interrupted) for the second time?

Are kernel's flusher and `write` mutually exclusive?

If not, is there a way to copy pages whole? Something like copying contents of one page into another by means of messing with virtual page pointers?